# How to create a bar or column chart inside a table cell of each column

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How to create a bar or column chart inside a table c[image: please find below image you can get clarity]ell of each column ?

we are expecting which react-libraries are using for doing this and small code snippets to achieve this.

Comment: Hi, a table cell element is like other HTML elements... You can just add the content you want inside the cells. Use your favorite chart library it will works. 
And for the snippets share yours first to see where you are stuck and the efforts you did.

Comment: Hi Alexis, thank you for your advice, but this data table built charts dynamically by using column data.